# TreeView creating custom nodes don't run the constructor

Tags: delphi

I want to use Treenodes with my own objects and have declared them like this:

```
MyObject1 = class(TTreeNode)
 aValue1 : integer; 
Public
 constructor Create(Owner: TTreeNodes);
 procedure .......
end;

MyObject2 = class(MyObject1)
 aValue2 : integer;
 public
 constructor Create(Owner: TTreeNodes);
 procedure ......
end;
```

In the `TreeView.OnCreateNodeClass` event, I set:

```
NodeClass := MyObject2;
```

When I then create a new node in my tree with:

```
TreeNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, '');
```

I believed that `MyObject2.Create` would be called, but it is not. The `MyObject2` is created as it should, so I can access the fields `aValue1` and `aValue2` when the node is created, but I would like to initialize them in my constructor.

Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `override` to each of your constructors to ensure that they will be called. You must also make sure that you call `inherited` in each constructor implementation.

> The `MyObject2` is created as it should so I can access the fields `aValue1` and `aValue2` when the node is created but I would like to initialize them in my constructor.

I don't think that is true. I think that when you try to access those fields you will just be accessing some random part of memory that is outside the actual node instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarify my mistakes David,